# Apple Pay didAuthorizePayment delegate and processing payment

Tags: ios, swift, payment-processing, applepay, payfort

I'm using Online payment gateway in my mobile app and now wanted to add Apple Pay feature as well for it is Secure and a hastle free method for online payments on Apple devices.

I've followed the basic guidelines as per Apple Pay docs and created all the `profiles and certificates` required to enable Apple Pay in my mobile app. And when tapped Apple Pay button the viewController is there with all the settings and payment options configured properly. Double tap the side button to Pay and the payment processing text appears, after 2-3 seconds the payment is done and `didAuthorizePayment` delegate is called. BUT now where am i supposed to enter the payment gateway request. Is it the didAuthorizePayment delegate or some other delegate.

If it is in `didAuthorizePayment` delegate, then I'm a bit confused here, as the `didAuthorizePayment` is already called and the ApplePay viewController shows done, so If i initiate payment gateway  request here and what if it is declined for some reasons.

I'm total confused here and all the tutorials and guidelines on the internet are about the steps that i've already covered.

Any helpful link or words are appreciated.

PS I'm using **Payfort Payment** gateway.

Comment: Hey did you find the answer?

Comment: Nah, not yet, got busy with something else. I'll try it again later this month. If you find something please drop a comment.